# Hide static URL in code

Tags: java, php, security, web

So let say I have a statement that let me get information and such from a link something like:

```
GetImage.getImage("www.image.net/image_1.png");
```

How would I hide the "www.image.net/image_1.png" from people obfuscating my software? If I put it in a txt file can't they just open up the file and see the link? If I put it on a version.php on a web host like "www.testwebsite.com/version.php", they can get the go to the website with that same URL and see the link I'm passing into the software?
I'm having a really difficult trying to understand the concepts of software security because of this.

Comment: You can't hide it in your code. That is a sad answer but it is the truth.

Comment: Well, which is it, [tag:java] or [tag:php]? Looks like Java, but one of those tags needs to go in any case. Also, note that people won't obfuscate your software. **You** might, to try to make it harder for them to reverse-engineer it.

Comment: Then how do major company keep the links to their update servers, log-in server, and stuff of the sort secure?

Comment: not possible. if it's code running on the client machine, then they can access it. doesn't matter how good/awesome your obfuscator is, it's still running in hostile territory.

Comment: @MikeNguyen: They don't. They make it *obscure*, but not *secure*. After all, no matter how well obfuscated it is, we can always use wireshark and watch the net request on the wire.

Comment: Ah, so I just need to find a way to make the URL to my database and such hard enough so it's tedious to reverse-engineer?

Comment: Secure mechanisms use authentication so that even if you have the address you can't mess with it. Explain your scenario, your question is much [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the client-side is JAVA but data and request/gets are going through by PHP

Comment: Make sure to use easily replaceable tokens.

Comment: @zapl I have a database and im trying to secure the link so client-side users can't access my database. My database login information is on a PHP script but to get information I have to past the URL of the script in the client-side program which give them access to the database if the software is deobfuscated by JD-GUI or something like that.

Comment: @MikeNguyen: Don't do that. Your server needs to be a gatekeeper. Only authenticated clients should be able to issue queries. Assume that anyone who wants to know the URL of your server will find out; ensure that it doesn't matter that they find out, by only allowing authenticated requests.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm not sure what you mean by having my server need to be a gatekeeper but I understand that I should only let authenticated clients do queries.

Comment: Even if you find a way to hide it in your code, the client can still check on their network traffic and figure out where their outgoing requests are going. Trying to keep the URL a "secret" is not a legitimate security precaution. Think of it this way: anyone can send requests to that URL, but in your server code, you must filter (authenticate) those requests accordingly.

Comment: So my client-side application will need to make a request to a script on my website which acts as a filter which will either push to the input data to my database or get information from my database and return it to the user?

Comment: @MikeNguyen Exactly. Client talks to your server only. You server can then decide whether that request is legitimate or not and do preprogrammed & safe things with the database. Deciding what db operations it allows is where user accounts come into play and help to restrict access to registered or even just paying customers and just the data they are granted accesss to. The database itself should never be exposed directly over the internet.

Answer (score 0):

The only real way you can fully hide where the file comes from is by having your server act as a proxy directly or not.  The file would first go to your server by some PHP request and then be made available to your visitor.

This would obviously increase your server's load and increase the bandwidth usage up to twice the transfer size of those images.

Answer (score -1):

If i understand your problem --> You can convert images to base64.

Comment: the image was just an example, but say for log-in information, database information etc.